# AWS Step Functions - include all step input but add a parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Let's say I have an AWS step function that simply passes the output from the first step to the second step.  But now let's say I need to add an additional input value for that second step.

How do I set the parameters for the second step to keep ALL input fields (without specifying them individually) and add a new input value?

The closest I can get is setting the Parameters like this:

```
"Second Step": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:blahblahblah",
  "InputPath": "$",
  "Parameters": {
    "Input.$":"$",
    "additionalValue": "ABC"
  }
}
```

But that results in pushing all of the input values under that new "Input" key, where I really just want them in the root of the dictionary.  I could swear there was some magic expression I saw once that made this work the way I want it to, but now I can't find it.

AWS now has a [simulator you can try this in](https://console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/simulator). Set InputPath to `$` and Parameters to `{"Input.$":"$","additionalValue":"ABC"}` to see an example of this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have this kind of manipulation with `ResultSelector`. But it can only be applied at ouput step. With this approach you need to either

- Alter the output of previous step with `ResultSelector`
- Create a pass-through step that add the static additional value you wanted

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  Wish there were a better way, though.  Really seems like an obvious gap.

Comment: A previous step is not an option when you need the current step to pass the extra parameters... like `AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID` during the call to another workflow:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-start-workflow.html

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works great using a chain of [Amazon States Language intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html):

```json
{
  "Comment": "Initializes and increments a counter without modifying the original workflow input.",
  "StartAt": "InitializeCounter",
  "States": {
    "InitializeCounter": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "IncrementCounter",
      "Parameters": {
        "output.$": "States.JsonMerge($, States.StringToJson('{\"counter\": 0}'), false)"
      },
      "OutputPath": "$.output"
    },
    "IncrementCounter": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "output.$": "States.JsonMerge($, States.StringToJson(States.Format('\\{\"counter\": {}\\}', States.MathAdd($.counter, 1))), false)"
      },
      "OutputPath": "$.output"
    }
  }
}
```

---

When I execute this with the input

```json
{
  "Comment": "Insert your JSON here"
}
```

the output of `InitializeCounter`, which is the input to `IncrementCounter`, is

```json
{
  "Comment": "Insert your JSON here",
  "counter": 0
}
```

and the output of `IncrementCounter` and indeed the whole workflow is

```json
{
  "Comment": "Insert your JSON here",
  "counter": 1
}
```

.

---

(Of course, `InitializeCounter` could also have been defined as

```json
{
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Next": "IncrementCounter",
  "Result": 0,
  "ResultPath": "$.counter"
}
```

but the purpose of this exercise is to devise a strategy that we could also use for the input of a Task/Activity state.)